# How to bypass the browser authentication on calling google form API, which uses oauth2?

Tags: python, authentication, data-extraction, google-forms-api

I want to automate the process of data extraction from google using pentaho, but during the execution of the script the browser is opened and asks for the selection of the gmail account for authentication, I am using OAuth authentication in my python code. The problem is that it creates the hurdle and requires human intervention to select the account for authentication.

How to avoid this either in the python code or is there another method of authentication which does not go for the browser authentication. Because in the google documentation only the authentication with the oauth2 is illustrated.

Here is the code which I am running:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import client, file, tools
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request  

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly"
DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"

store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = None
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
            print("need to open browser for authentication")    
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = discovery.build('forms', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(
    Http()), discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC, static_discovery=False)

# Prints the responses of your specified form:
form_id = '<form_id>'
result = service.forms().responses().list(formId=form_id).execute()
print(result)
```

here is the image of browser which opens during the execution of the script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yduIP.png)

Answer (score -1):

have also been on this same issue for some days now...and am finding it difficult understand why google has to seek for authentication after i have generated an API Key

Comment: Hi! This reply doesn't answer OP's question. Please consider posting answers that are helpful for answering the question.